# Writing an efficient BackboneJS application with shared data across multiple users

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

I'm currently creating my first BackboneJS application and it's become apparent that every time the index view is opened, the user needs to see the latest data from the server.

The best approach I can think of is to send push notifications to the Backbone applications running on multiple user's computers when data is updated on the server. However, before I jump ahead on that solution, is there any better alternatives?

I currently have the view fetching the collection from the server each time it's viewed.

Comment: That's more a generic problem than a Backbone's one. What you in fact want is to use websockets. There are other solutions to mimic this behavior though.

Comment: Yes and no, it ties in with the collections setup by Backbone. I have found a couple of push notification libraries since writing this question. https://github.com/pusher/backpusher https://github.com/bluedevil2k/backbone-live